# How to use node.js module with Angular 6?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular6

I am newbie in Angular 6 and TypeScript. Can someone show me the right way to use node.js third-party module in Angular 6?

For example i want to create component with ability to consume and make requests to SOAP wsdl methods.

Did installed it by adding to package.json with `npm install`.

Trying to use node-soap npm module like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as soap from 'node-soap';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MySoapService {
  constructor() { }

  getOrderInfo() {
    const url = 'http://my-example-api.com/WCF/ClientService.svc?singleWsdl';
    let args = {
      login: 'login',
      password: 'password',
      orderNumber: 'F976638'
    };
    soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
      client.GetOrderInfo(args, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
      });
    });
  };
}
```

Then inject this service into component and render it, just to test the service...

But got some error during `ng serve`:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/node-soap/client.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/cadistortion/WebstormProjects/my-ng-app/node_modules/node-soap'
```

Thank you!

Comment: node libraries are meant to execute in a NodeJS environment, on the server. Angular is a client-side framework: an Angular application executes in the browser. You can't just take any node library and use it in an Angular application.

Comment: @JBNizet - seems a fair question. In theory, they are both Javascript. Why couldn't some of the simpler node functions (without server dependencies) be re-used client side? Found Some thoughts on this here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-share-code-between-node-js-and-the-browser/

Answer (score -2):

it's easy, in your url have your API node.
You go need more, express.js(or other) for get work.
BD - like MongoDB or other or Json.

See this vídeo and other the same user https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-G48Gf2Xl0
is complete how create blog using MEAN Stack