# How to use a Node Javascript library in Angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

I am using Angular 8. This is the NPM library that I want to use : https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-units

However, it is probably for Node.js, as it seems. Is there any way to make it work in my Angular component?

Comment: Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51712942/how-to-use-node-js-module-with-angular-6) question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you definitely can use many of the NPM packages in the browser (Angular, React or any other framework/tech stack).

As for `convert-units` package. Just install it using `npm install convert-units --save` and then import using either:

```js
const convert = require("convert-units"); // as according to documentation
```

or

```js
import * as convert from "convert-units"; // to use new ES syntax
```

Example: 
[image: Edit npm convert-units]

Comment: Getting this error - "resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct."

Comment: @RayNorman try to use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51758340/4358597

Comment: @AlexeyVolkov: How to make 'Convert' available thought the angular application?

Answer (score 0):

As it is a utility package you can use it in node as well as angular. 
For angular you have to change the import to

```
import convert from 'convert-units';
```

Answer (score 0):

First install the npm package as

```
npm install convert-units --save
```

Then in your component import as given below

```
import convert from 'convert-units';
```

Please find the working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-u27n5j

Comment: Thanks for the  answer. I am getting this error. ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(2,8): error TS1192: Module '"C:/Users/M1049043/Desktop/unit/unitt/node_modules/@types/convert-units/index"' has no default export.

Comment: Can you try to rebuild your application and test it.

Comment: I did. Getting this error - "resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.
"

Comment: Are you using "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true in your tsconfig.json? If not, can you please add this and try

Comment: Yes, I am. Still, the "convert-units" part in the import statement is being marked red.